# difficulty implementing minimax algorithm for a tic-tac-toe game in java

Tags: java, algorithm

I am trying to make a tic-tac-toe game in java,with an array of objects cell[i][j],where cell stores the value of the of ith  row and jth column ,with the help of setToken() and getToken(),problem is with the minimax algorithm,player plays as maximiser('x') and the AI as minimiser('O'),irrespective of what player plays the AI is simply playing the next free box available,i highly suspect there is some problem with either of these 2 functions....please help!
'

```
Move findBestMove(Cell cell[][])
{
    int bestVal = 1000;
    Move bestMove = new Move();
    bestMove.row = 3;
    bestMove.col = 3;


    for (int i = 0; i<3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j<3; j++)
        {

            if (cell[i][j].getToken()==' ')
            {
                // Make the move
                cell[i][j].setToken('O');

                // compute evaluation function for this
                // move.
                int moveVal = minimax(cell, 0, true);

                // Undo the move
                cell[i][j].setToken(' ');

                // If the value of the current move is
                // more than the best value, then update
                // best/
                if (moveVal < bestVal)
                {
                    bestMove.row = i;
                    bestMove.col = j;
                    bestVal = moveVal;
                }
            }
        }
    }


System.out.println("best move " + bestMove.row  + bestMove.col);
    return bestMove;
}`
```

**and of course the minimax()**

`int minimax(Cell cell[][], int depth, boolean isMax)
    {
        int score = evaluate(cell);

```
    // If Maximizer has won the game return his/her
    // evaluated score
    if (score == 10)
        return score-depth;

    // If Minimizer has won the game return his/her
    // evaluated score
    if (score == -10)
        return score+depth;


    // it is a tie
    if (isMovesLeft(cell)==false)
        return 0;

    // If this maximizer's move
    if (isMax)
    {
        int best = -1000;

        // Traverse all cells
        for (int i = 0; i<3; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j<3; j++)
            {
                // Check if cell is empty
                if (cell[i][j].getToken()==' ')
                {
                    // Make the move
                    cell[i][j].setToken('X');

                    // Call minimax recursively and choose

                    best = java.lang.Math.max( best,
                        minimax(cell, depth+1, isMax) );

                    // Undo the move
                    cell[i][j].setToken(' ');
                }
            }
        }
        return best;
    }

    // If this minimizer's move
    else
    {
        int best = 1000;

        // Traverse all cells
        for (int i = 0; i<3; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j<3; j++)
            {
                // Check if cell is empty
                if (cell[i][j].getToken()==' ')
                {
                    // Make the move
                    cell[i][j].setToken('O');


                    best = java.lang.Math.min(best,
                           minimax(cell, depth+1, !isMax));

                    // Undo the move
                  cell[i][j].setToken(' ');
                }
            }
        }
        return best;
    }
}
```

`

Comment: `if (moveVal < bestVal)...`?  Check that test again, especially in light of the preceding comment: "// If the value of the current move is **more than the best value**, then update best".

Comment: yeah,actually I updated that part but forgot to update the comment,as the AI plays as minimizer the lesser will be the value of bestVal the better will be the move for AI....

Comment: but btw even changing that part(comment) wouldn't help.....